# How to convert a positive signed int32 value to its negative one?

Tags: go

I have try to write one logic is to convert an `int32` positive value to a corresponding negative one, i.e., `abs(negativeInt32) == positiveInt32`.

I have tried with both:

- First:

  ```
  fmt.Printf("%v\n", int32(^uint32(int32(2) -1)))
  ```

  This results in an error : `prog.go:8: constant 4294967294 overflows int32`
- Second:

  ```
  var b int32 = 2
  fmt.Printf("%v\n", int32(^uint32(int32(b)-1)))
  ```

  This results in `-2`.

How can both result in different results. I think they are equal.
[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/zipqfzVkk6)

#### EDIT

Edit for replacing `uint32` with `int32` for the first situation.

#### ANSWERED

For those who come to this problem, I have answered the question myself. :)

Comment: Why not just `-b`?

Comment: @Ainar-G, This is partial code of a function, i want to make the function invoked like `DecrBy(10)`, which is more natural, instead `DecrBy(-10)`

Answer (score 1):

The two results are different because the first value is typecast to an *unsigned* int32 (a `uint32`).

This occurs here: `uint32(^uint32(int32(2) -1))`
Or more simply: `uint32(-2)`

An `int32` can store any integer between -2147483648 and 2147483647.
That's a total of 4294967296 different integer values (2^32... i.e. 32 bits).

An *unsigned* int32 can store the same **amount** of different integer values, but drops the signage (+/-). In other words, an *unsigned* int32 can store any value from 0 to 4294967295.

But what happens when we typecast a *signed* int32 (with a value of -2) to an *unsigned* int32, which cannot possibly store the value of -2?

Well as you have found, we get the value of 4294967294. Which in a number system where one integer less than 0 is 4294967295; 4294967294 happens to be the sum of 0 - 2.

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating your solution. Forget all the type casting, just do `2 * -1`. a-la http://play.golang.org/p/Y2CgPeQSF8 or http://play.golang.org/p/TdhvyM3Yxv.

Comment: that is incredible easy and work around it. awesome.:)

Answer (score 1):

Hello You can simply try below code

```
var z int32 =5
a:=-(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally, i have learned that why we can not do

```
fmt.Printf("%v\n", int32(^uint32(int32(2) -1)))
```

at compile time. It is that `^uint32(int32(2)-1)` is treated as a `constant` value with `uint32` type. It's value is `4294967294`. This exceeds the maximum value of `int32` for `2147483647`. So when you run `go build` on the source code file. `Compile error` is shown.

The right answer to this should be:

```
fmt.Printf("%v\n, ^(int32(2) - 1))
```

i.e., we should first get the corresponding value of `1` in `int32` type and, then convert it to the [`two's complementary form`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) as value of `-1`.

However, according to [this golang blog](https://blog.golang.org/constants)'s `An exercise: The largest unsigned int` section, this is legal in runtime. So the code

```
var b int32 = 2
fmt.Printf("%v\n", int32(^uint32(int32(b)-1)))
```

is alright.

And, finally it comes to that this is related to constants in Golang. :)